# Which JMX statistics to watch out for in Catalina/Tomcat?

Tags: monitoring, tomcat, jmx

I have configured OpenNMS to collect all kinds of numeric data coming out of tomcat7 jmx. There are a lot of things. I am interested in monitoring this tomcat instance so that I can avoid down time and lockups. What metrics should I be watching out for?

I am already monitoring things like CPU, Memory, Network via SNMP. With this JMX connection the things that I find interesting are

- Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name="ajp-bio-/a.b.c.d-XXXX"

  - RequestsCount so far.
- Catalina:type=Manager,context=/myApp,host=localhost

  - Active sessions and its maximum so far

Answer (score 1):

For Tomcat 6, I monitored thread pools using: **Catalina:type=ThreadPool,***

Not sure whether you need application level statistics - if yes, some of the MBeans you might find interesting are:

- Servlet Activity: **Catalina:j2eeType=Servlet,*** (I am sure there is one for JSP as well)
- DataSource: **Catalina:type=DataSource,***
- Cache hits: **Catalina:type=Cache,***

Note: I assume these object names are the same in Tomcat 7